# Embed a PDF in github/gitlab wiki

Tags: pdf, github, gitlab, pdf-viewer

I'm using gitlab to manage my repositories which has been quite pleasant so far. However the wiki could use a fair amount of improvement IMO.

It's really annoying when you already have documentation that you simply want to add to the wiki. Translating a table or pdf to gitlab flavored markdown can be time consuming and non-trivial.

My question is two-fold.

1. Has anyone had luck embedding files (specifically pdf's) into their github/gitlab wiki? This should definitely be possible on gitlab but is their an easy way to do it? I have a documentation repo set up, it would be awesome to embed files linked from the documentation repo.
2. **If not embedding files into the pages. How do you efficiently translate a document to gitlab flavored markdown?**

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and landed here, maybe this helps somebody.

I didn't find a way to embed the .pdf into a page but what I did was to add the .pdf to the wiki folder (like a normal page). Initially this didn't show up in the sidebar nor was it searchable from Github.

It is possible however to link it directly from other pages or a custom sidebar (see for example [osquery's wiki](https://github.com/facebook/osquery/wiki) for a nice sidebar). Clicking on the link allows you to download the .pdf (didn't find a way to preview it in the browser)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've just about abandoned the Github/Gitlab wiki due to the effort you need to put in to translating existing documentation.

Comment: How do you add a pdf to the wiki folder like a normal page?  Do you mean we should add the pdf to the git repo then link to it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that such action type is not allowed only in cloud gitlab version, cause gitlab-gollum lib documentation [describes it so](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gitlab-gollum-lib/1.0.0/file/README.md#FILE_LINKS):

`[[Gollum|gollum.pdf]]`

Answer (score 0):

I use Gitlab (self hosted) capabilities to render MarkDown pages regularly for documenting my projects.

The best way to copy paste html or pdf documentation and translate into perfectly formatted MarkDown is to use [Typora](https://typora.io/). Typora has these very useful capabilities:

- Support for Gitlab TOC rendering (i.e. `[[_TOC_]]`)
- copy and paste from HTML pages to MarkDown
- upload of images

IMO is very easy to use for documentation with GitLab.